# android canvas click failure T_T

Tags: android, canvas, click, draw

i need draw some stuff on canvas and then lick on each. I made a class

```
public class PlayGameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

In this class I have onDraw method

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas  canvas) {     
        Paint  paint = new Paint (); 
        Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);
        canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, canvas.getWidth()/2 - wrench.getWidth()*2 + i*wrench.getWidth(), 0  + j*wrench.getHeight(), null);
            }
        }

}
```

and inner class Thread.
so, in xml file i added this View like this

```
    <com.cerbertek.PlayGameView
    android:id="@+id/play_field_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and tying to add clicklistener in activity class

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_game);

    playField = (PlayGameView) findViewById(R.id.play_field_surface_view);
    playField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(PlayGameActivity.this, "ОХУЕТЬ", 2000);          
        }
    });
}
```

but nothing happens. no toast. when i called getWidth method it showed me ZERO! But I see the image)

how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to [show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show%28%29) it:

```
Toast.makeText(PlayGameActivity.this, "ОХУЕТЬ", 2000).show();
```